# Python - convert multiple insert statements into one

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have the following problem right now:

I have a database table with only 2 columns: ID (`primary key, auto increment`) and value (`varchar(100)`).

Now I have a `sql` file to fill that table with values. Here comes the point though: First of all, the text file has only single inserts, so every value inserted is a single value. Wouldn't be a problem in general, if it wouldn't be about 10 million lines...

To make it even more funny, I've got 5 of this tables and 5 of this `.sql` files with the insert statements.

Now I've tried to run the sql file as it is and for even only 100k lines, it took an hour... So inserting 10 million entries would take about 100 hours... x5 for all tables would take about 500 hours then, being about 21 days.. Nothing that I'd like to see going on here...

Now from what I've read, the speed would be much faster, if one insert statement would contain multiple values to insert... for example:

```
insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! -');

insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! 3');

insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! 5');

insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! ?');

insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! C');

insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! c');
```

would become:

```
insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! -','! 3','! 5','! ?','! C''! c');
```

As an example...  From what I've read, about 40 values per insert statement will be a pretty good value...

So thats what I'd like to get.. From a sql file with 400 single statements (as an example) to an sql file with 10 statements with 40 values each.

Now I've tried around a lot with regular expressions and different methods in Notepad++ as an example, but I couldn't really get it working...

I then though if python might be able to do this in an elegant way (either inserting it directly into the database or just converting the text file). I figured that inserting wouldn't help much, so now I'm looking for a way to convert the file into another file, just that it has the mentioned decrease of single statements..

My **pseudo code** for that would be something like:

```
open file.sql
i = 0;
for each line in file.sql:
   if i==40:
      i=0
      break
   else:
      remove text "insert into knownPasswords3 (password) values ("
      remove text ");"
      add text ,
```

However, I've tried that and just can't get these parts working...

Can anybody put me on the right track for that? is there maybe a lib or sth making that easier?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the insert statement you are trying to prepare.It should look like this :

```
insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! -'),('! 3'),('! 5'),('! ?'),('! C'),('! c');
```

now you are inserting 6 rows with 1 column whereas your query was inserting 1 row with 6 columns.

Comment: yeah, okay, there might be an issue in what I typed here.. however, the question is, how to get my multiple single insert statements into some bigger statements (with 40 each)?

Comment: either manually or using custom code ,  replace `insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ` with `,`  except the very first one and your query is ready

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what I wrote in my question... i just don't know how to really get this working in python...especially keeping in mind, that each insert statement should have about 40 values insert, and not 10 million at once

Answer (score 1):

This code is based purely on file handling, list slicing and string manipulation. It reads a file named "file.sql" and saves insert statements with 40 values each in a second file named "file2.sql".

Hope this answers your question.

```
# reading the lines from SQL file
file1 = open('file.sql', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
file1.close()

# removing the first line
lines.pop(0)

# getting a list of all the values
list_of_values = []
for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
  list_of_values.append(lines[i].split("'")[1])  

# setting the limits to 40 elements per insert statement
lowerlimit = -40
upperlimit = 0

# flag to check whether the number of values left is greater than 40
remaining_values = True

# second file to save output
file2 = open('file2.sql', 'w')

while remaining_values:

  # setting flag if remaining values less than 40
  if len(list_of_values)-upperlimit <= 40:
    remaining_values = False

  # updating limits as we move traverse the list
  lowerlimit = upperlimit
  upperlimit = min(upperlimit + 40, len(list_of_values)) 

  # formulating insert statement
  output = 'insert into knownPasswords3 (password)\nvalues '

  # adding 40 values to each insert statement
  if remaining_values == True:
    output += str(list_of_values[lowerlimit:upperlimit]).replace('[','(').replace(']',')') + ";\n\n"
  else:
    output += str(list_of_values[lowerlimit:upperlimit]).replace('[','(').replace(']',')') + ";"

  # writing insert statement to output file
  n = file2.write(output)    

# closing the file
file2.close()
```

Testing on a sample file, it gives the following output:

```
insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?');


insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3');


insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c');


insert into knownPasswords3 (password)
values ('! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c', '! -', '! 3', '! 5', '! ?', '! C', '! c');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. in general, this seems to be fine, however, I seem to have codec issues at that point...getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6381: character maps to <undefined>`.... tried opening with `econdig='utf-8'` but threw an error as well... tried with `rb` as mode for binary, but then it has a problem when appending it to the list.. any idea?

Comment: You misspelled `encoding` as `econdig` there.

Comment: Also, what sort of characters are there in your file? I might be able to help if I get hold of the file, or even a subset which causes error.

Comment: @yeah, that was actually just a typo here on stackoverflow.. also, I uploaded one file now over here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9aa3f5d1daee7707f207fdfb0e3438cd20210121214059/24e12c
thats the file where it fails right now as well... you can try it with that

Comment: @nameless that is because there are some non ascii character in the file, you should format properly the file before passing it to the open function. It seems an error in the end of line character

Comment: if you delete that invisible char and put the insert statement all in one line both this script and mine should work fine.

Comment: @Aelius do you know where the problem is? Because I checked the file... its just these characters in the brackets and then CR LF for every end of line/line break.. also, I ran all files through `iconv` before, in order to make sure its only utf-8... do you know where the problem is exactly?

Comment: @ahmadjanan so I got the bad characters.. I used `[^\x00-\x7F]+` as regex and just replaced it wiht nothing, so they are all gone... however, now I get a `list index out of range` error...

Comment: got it working now! :) there are some minor things I need to change but it seems to be working :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Consider marking my post as the answer, if it answered your question. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_transactions?view=powershell-5.1). They group statements together that must all be executed together or none execute (kind of like multiple statements treated as one statement). Not fully sure if it is what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
infile = open('file.sql', 'r' )

ins_stmnts = {}
for line in infile:
    if 'insert' in line:
      ins_stmnt, vals = line.split('values')
      if ins_stmnt in ins_stmnts.keys():
        ins_stmnts[ins_stmnt].append(vals)
      else:
        ins_stmnts[ins_stmnt] = [vals]

infile.close()

outfile = open("converted.sql", 'w')

for ins_stmnt, vals in ins_stmnts.items():
  val_str = "("
  for i, val in enumerate(vals):
    if i%39==0:
      val = val.rstrip(');\n')
      val = val.lstrip(' (')
      val_str += val
      outfile.write(ins_stmnt + "values " + val_str + ');\n')
      val_str = "("
      break
    else:
      val = val.rstrip(');\n')
      val = val.lstrip(' (')
      val_str += val + ','

  if len(val_str)>1:
    outfile.write(ins_stmnt + "values " + val_str.rstrip(',') + ');\n')

outfile.close()
```